NMR pulse sequence for precise measurements of coupling constants?
The usual procedure for measuring $J$ coupling constants in NMR is to record a 1D spectrum and estimate the constant from the differences of peak frequencies. Fitting the spectrum to a lineshape function will probably give better results than doing this by hand. Zero-filling and apodisation can also be used to make the spectrum look better.
However, I was thinking - what if one wanted to measure the value of some coupling constant very precisely. Is there some pulse sequence or data processing technique that would improve upon the method above? What about values of coupling constants that are very small (e.g. less than 0.2 Hz), so one would not even see them in the 1D spectra because of the inherent line broadening - is there a special technique for that?

E.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.pnmrs.2018.08.003. Homonuclear, heteronuclear? Large or small molecules? Natural abundance or labeled? Which nucleus?

My original thought was $^1$H homonuclear coupling in small-ish molecules (let's say C$_{20}$ or less). But hearing about any other possibilities would also be interesting.

Google Scholar shows plenty of papers on J resolved NMR spectroscopy.

I don't have experience running these experiments specifically, but one option that I'm aware of is selective refocusing (SERF) experiments — see e.g. Angew. Chem., Int. Ed. 2010, 49, 3481. These work by first removing all couplings (using a Zangger–Sterk pure shift element, i.e. field gradient combined with selective pulse) and then specifically re-introducing coupling to one proton (by application of a selective pulse to that proton).
What you get out of it is something like a classic 2DJ spectrum, but with only the couplings to the selected proton shown in the indirect dimension — so in the indirect dimension everything is a doublet (assuming you inverted only one proton). This lets you directly read off the coupling constant.
Traditional 2DJ spectroscopy gives you multiplets in the indirect dimension with all the couplings being. You can still do this, but I would suggest doing the PSYCHE version of it as it will give you much better resolution: Chem. Commun. 2015, 51, 15410.
For heteronuclear couplings you could try doing IPAP type experiments. Running these will give you two different spectra, with the same multiplet appearing in both, but being offset by the coupling constant. You can retrieve the coupling constant by superimposing the two and measuring. See e.g. J. Magn. Reson. 2010, 207, 312.
I don't think any of these would let you resolve couplings on the order of 0.2 Hz, though. That's a tough ask for any NMR method.

Here is one example of measuring “exceedingly small” coupling constants: https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1018373601391

@Karsten Ooh, that's very clever! Measuring peak intensities for different mixing times and fitting to an equation wasn't what I had in mind, I was thinking of methods to directly read it off a spectrum. But that's a great bit of work. Do you think it would work for 1H?

Grzesiek is the clever guy for this paper. In proteins, the nitrogen atoms have no other nitrogen atoms as coupling partners nearby. This might be different for hydrogen for most molecules, making the strategy less appealing.

Ah, I see what you mean — it would be a lot harder to derive and fit an equation where multiple coupling partners are present.
